# Last login a user in OpenLdap

Tags: ldap, openldap, slapd, ldapsearch

I am running openldap 2.4.45. Is there anyway I can get the last login time of a user using authtimestamp or any other attribute?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable inactive OpenLDAP accounts](https://serverfault.com/questions/1126055/how-to-disable-inactive-openldap-accounts)