# How to disable inactive OpenLDAP accounts

Tags: openldap

is there a means to disable such OpenLDAP accounts that show no interaction for a given grace period. In particular, of a user has not logged in to her account since x days (no matter the means of authentication), can the account be disabled directly?

So far, I have only read about configurations that are a bit "hackish", enforcing the user the change the password during said grace period and then setting pwdGraceAuthnLimit to 0 (see https://www.openldap.org/lists/openldap-software/200803/msg00142.html).

However, this is not exactly what I would like to achieve, i.e. the hack to enforce a password reset is not what I want.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default OpenLDAP does not record a last logon, nor AFAIK any or similar data that you can use/abuse to find inactive accounts.

But you can extend OpenLDAP with the [lastbind overlay](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/slapo-lastbind.5.html) and then it will provide a `authTimestamp` attribute:

> The  lastbind  overlay  to  slapd(8) allows recording the timestamp of the last successful
> bind to entries in the directory, in the authTimestamp  attribute.   The  overlay  can  be
> configured  to update this timestamp only if it is older than a given value, thus avoiding
> large numbers of write operations penalizing performance.  One sample use for this overlay
> would be to detect unused accounts.

Install the overlay, edit slapd.conf and restart OpenLDAP

```
       # ETCDIR/slapd.conf

       # ...

       overlay lastbind
       lastbind-precision 68400
```

IIRC there are some caveats as for example the `authTimestamp` attribute appears to be  specific to a particular OpenLDAP server and is excluded from replication. Any reports will then need to query all your OpenLDAP servers to find the most recent last logon date.

---

Once enabled you will need to  create a script that finds accounts whose `authTimestamp`  exceeds your idea of too long ago since last successful logon  and lock them.